# Screen Mirroring with Chromecast

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, nexus-7, chromecast, screencast

I have two devices - a Samsung Galaxy S3 and a Nexus 7 (2012 version) - that I'm trying to mirror to a Chromecast. It looks like neither device supports screen mirroring on Chromecast with the default app. I also installed [EZCast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionsmicro.ezcast) on the Nexus 7 but the EZMirror is not enabled on it.

Is there any way, (third party apps, rooting?) wherein I can cast my screen from any of the above two devices to Chromecast?

Answer (score 2):

The original Nexus 7 **does** support screen mirroring to Chromecast. This feature was added in Android 4.4, so if you're still using an old Android version on your Nexus 7, you'll need to do a system update. From the **Settings** app, go to **Display** then **Cast screen**. Don't bother with the Chromecast app at all.

The option's in a different place on the S3, and it's designed primarily for Samsung's competitor to the Chromecast, but I expect it would work with both. From the **Settings** app, at the bottom of the **Connections** page, click **Screen Mirroring**. The phone will start looking for devices it can cast to.

Comment: It doesn't work as you suggested. they cant identify Chomecast

Comment: You should probably ask a new question about your specific problem so that people will see it and be able to answer. Make sure to give full details of the problem.